# Postfix - MySQL - noreply custom response not working

Tags: mysql, email, postfix, email-server

I'm trying to get a custom response working for no.reply@example.com and I keep getting "User doesn't exist" errors.

I have an alias of no.reply@example.com which has a 'goto' of the same value, then I have a `custom_replies` file which has the following:

```
no.reply@example.com REJECT Sorry, but no.reply@example.com is not a monitored email address.
```

In the `/etc/postfix/main.cf` file I have:

```
check_recipient_access = hash:/etc/postfix/conf.d/custom_replies
```

And the `/etc/postfix/master.cf` file:

```
smtp        inet  n       -       -       -       -       smtpd
  -o content_filter=spamassassin
submission  inet  n       -       n       -       -       smtpd
  -o content_filter=spamassassin
  -o milter_macro_daemon_name=ORIGINATING
  -o smtpd_recipient_restrictions=check_recipient_access,permit_mynetworks,permit_sasl_authenticated,reject_unauth_destination
  -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
  -o smtpd_sasl_path=private/auth
  -o smtpd_sasl_type=dovecot
  -o smtpd_tls_security_level=encrypt
  -o smtpd_tls_wrappermode=no
  -o syslog_name=postfix/submission
```

What I think is happening is that the alias no.reply@example.com -> no.reply@example.com is failing before custom_replies is considered. Is this possible, or is there a better approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, looks like `check_recipient_access` isn't the way to go for this. I found this [post](https://www.pitt-pladdy.com/blog/_20120108-210134_0000_Postfix_config_for_noreply_domain_tld/) and got it to work using `smtpd_end_of_data_restrictions`.

Snippet from main.cf

```
smtpd_end_of_data_restrictions = check_recipient_access,hash:/etc/postfix/conf.d/custom_replies,permit
```